# few architectural issues building a cocoa framework

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, frameworks

I'm building a cocoa framework and i gonna change one question.
I got a few issues trying to use an own framework that i'm building, the first time I have compiled by default in Standard architecture (x86_64) but when I try to use some classes on it I get a warning on the project that uses it:

> id: warning: ignoring file ..... file was built for x86_64 file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

and I think that is for this reason that I can excecute the methods on the classes,
So I try to change the architecture for the framework to 32 bis (i386) but i get a failure:

> -fobj-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime.

The framework only compiles in 64 bits but doesnt work on the project.

Comment: Do you actually need to build for 32-bit for any reason? If not, then don't. ARC only works in 64-bit, so if you're using ARC, you can't build for 32-bit. There's little reason to support 32-bit at this point unless you need to support legacy hardware and OSes.

Comment: thanks buddy, actually i need build for 32 bits (:/). I'm learning cocoa, so, how do I realize that i'm using ARC, build settings or something?

Comment: Yes, it's a build setting. If you go to the project settings (by clicking on the project in the Project Navigator pane), and select "Build Settings", you'll see a search box. Enter "reference" and one of the settings that will show up is "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting". Set it to "No" and that will turn off ARC.

Comment: thanks a lot man, i should add some cflags (-fno-objc-arc) in my *.mm files, now i got another problem with the framework, i can compile it in 32/64 bits, but when i run the plugin it doesn't work, seems like the group that develop the application had the same problem
(http://osirixpluginbasics.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/osirix-doesnt-see-plugin/#comment-8479) so i'm asking now, do you have an idea of an standard for framework developing? like Cocoa, Foundation, or the OsiriXAPI that they're using? 
thanks